# How to Join to Entity in Get method asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

i have problem

i have  A  CategoryEntity Class :

```
 public class Category : IId
    {
        [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubToCat> SubToCat { get; set; }
    }
```

and SubCategory Entity Class :

```
public class SubCategory : IId
    {
        [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubToCat> SubToCat { get; set; }
    }
```

and its my SubToCat entity class :

```
  public class SubToCat
    {
        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

now in Get method for all SubCategory i want to join the all of categories where its CategoryId is same as CategoryId
but i dont know how, Can you plz Help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using some Entity Framework :

```
_dbContext.SubCategories.Where(s => s.SubToCat.Category == CategoryId)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need join.  Just use SelectMany as code below :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataContext db = new DataContext();

            var results = db.Category.SelectMany(x => x.SubToCat.SelectMany(y => y.SubCategory.SubToCat.Select(z => new {
                catId = x.Id, 
                catName = x.Name, 
                subToSubCatId = y.SubCategoryId,
                subToCatId = y.CategoryId,
                subToCategory = y.Category,
                subToCatSubCatId = z.SubCategory.Id,
                subToCatSubCatName = z.SubCategory.Name
            }).ToList():


        }
    }
    public class DataContext
    {
        public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
    }
    public class IId
    {
    }
    public class Category : IId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubToCat> SubToCat { get; set; }
    }
    

    public class SubCategory : IId
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<SubToCat> SubToCat { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubToCat
    {
        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```cs
_dbContext.SubCategories
    .Include(x => x.SubToCat)
    .Include(x => x.Category)
```

This will bring in all Sub Categories as well the joining table and relevant Categories in a single SQL Query using 2 joins.

Comment: I think the second Include should be "x.SubToCat.Category".